# openpyxl generating broken workbook

Tags: python, excel, pymongo, openpyxl

I have the following code that get data from MongoDB and write it in excel, but its giving an error when I open the Workbook generated ("We found a problem in ~workbook_name~... ").

Code:

```
ws = wb.active
client = pymongo.MongoClient("...")
db = client['...']
collection = db['...']
r = 2
for doc in collection.find({'is_timeline_valid': True}):
    for dic in doc['timeline']['datas']:
        if 'pedido' in dic['tramite'].lower():
           ws.cell(row = r, column = 1).value =doc['id_process_unformatted']
        ws.cell(row = r, column = 2).value = dic['data']
        ws.cell(row = r, column = 3).value = dic['tramite']
        wb.save('pedido.xlsx')
        print('*****************************')
        print(dic['tramite'])
        # print('check!')
        r += 1
```

Comment: Try using `dic` not `doc` in ws.cell(row = r, column = 1).value =doc['id_process_unformatted']. You may want to set the value as string by getting the string representation.

Comment: why? id_process_unformatted is a key of doc not of dic.

Comment: Oh my bad. I actually thought it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Save the workbook when setting cell values is complete.

Also, convert the values set in the cell to an appropriate format. I opted to use `str` here. You can use `json.dumps` depending on the content of the values.

```
from itertools import count
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
client = pymongo.MongoClient("...")
db = client['...']
collection = db['...']
valid_timelines = collection.find({'is_timeline_valid': True})
counter = count(start=2)

for doc in valid_timelines:
    for row, dic in zip(counter, doc['timeline']['datas']):
        if 'pedido' in dic['tramite'].lower():
           ws.cell(row=row, column=1, value=str(doc['id_process_unformatted']))

        ws.cell(row=row, column=2, value=str(dic['data']))
        ws.cell(row=row, column=3, value=str(dic['tramite']))

wb.save('pedido.xlsx')
```

Comment: Maybe the save is the problem. But as I have lots of data in mongo I can't save at the end, so saving in portions is a possible solution. Thanks a lot @Oluwafemi

Comment: You can try to save on every `n` rows or so. `if row % n == 0: wb.save()`. There is also need to account for rows added in the end.